# How to show up matched result when input text is delete one by one

Tags: jquery, filter

I can manage to show up matched result by inputting letter to filter field, but I can make the same matched result show up when the "backspace" (deleting letter one by one) is pressed. For example, if I type in "K","U","S" in the following example, the K and B rows show up, but if I remove "S","U" one by one, so the result should any words with "K" letter, in my code it does not.

Also, after the no matched result message show up, if I delete the letter one by one, the result show blank instead of matched result.

```js
$(function($) {
  var list = { letters:[] };
  var $ul = $("<ul></ul>").appendTo(".page-content");
   $(".page-content").append("<p id='no_result_found'></p>");
   
  $("nav.link-list a").each(function(itmLetter) {
    var brandTitle = $(this).attr("title");
    itmLetter = brandTitle.trim().substring(0, 1).toUpperCase();
    if (list.letters.indexOf(itmLetter) < 0) {
       list[itmLetter] = [];
        list.letters.push(itmLetter);
      $ul.append(
        $("<li/>", {
          "class": "AddContent",
          "id": itmLetter,
          "data-content": itmLetter
        })
      ); // end of $ul.append()
    } // end of if statement

     // push letters to each nav-list
       list[itmLetter].push($(this));

  }); // end of alphabet list

    list.letters.sort();
    $("article.category-list").empty();
    $.each(list.letters, function(i, letter){
        list[letter].sort(function(a, b) {
            return $(a).text().toUpperCase().localeCompare($(b).text().toUpperCase());
        }); // end of letters.sort()

         var ul = $("<ul/>");
         $.each(list[letter], function(idx, itm){
              ul.append(itm);
          }); // end of .each()
    
         $("article.category-list").append($("<nav/>").addClass("link-list").append($("<h3/>").addClass("alphabet").html(letter)).append(ul));
}); // end of .each()

$("li.AddContent").click(function() {
       var al = $(this).attr("id");
      $("nav.link-list").each(function(){
          var brand =  $(this).find("a").attr("title");
           $(this).css("display", "none").filter(function(){
           return brand.trim().substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() == al;
      }).prependTo("article.category-list").fadeIn(500);
   }); //end of each()
 }); //end of click()

// filter field
   $("input#searchTerm").on("keyup", function(){
         var inputValue = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
         var checkEmpty = [];
          
         $("nav.link-list ul").children("a").each(function(){
             var brand =  $(this).attr("title");

                 if (brand.toLowerCase().indexOf(inputValue) > -1) {
                       checkEmpty.push('1');
                       $(this).fadeIn(800)
                } else {
                      $(this).css("display", "none");
                }
          
     }); // end of .each()
      if ($("nav.link-list ul").children("a").is("visible")) {$("nav.link-list ul").parent().addClass("active");}
if(checkEmpty.length == 0)
        {
         $('#no_result_found').html('Sorry, no matched result is found, please try again.');
        }
        else
        {
          $('#no_result_found').html('');
        }
        $('.link-list').each(function(){
          var item=$(this);
          if(item.find('a').get().length==item.find('a:hidden').get().length) {
          item.hide();
          }
          else {
          item.show();
          }
        });
        if(inputValue.length==0){
        $('.link-list').show();
        }
        
        

  }); // end of .on(keyup)
    
    // no result
   
}); //end of script
```

```css
.AddContent:before {
   content: attr(data-content);
}

.page-content h1 {
    display: inline;
    float: left;
}

/**** search field ****/
.page-content__body {
    display: block;
    float: right;
    position: relative;
    top: 24px;
    width: 20%;
}
.search {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative
}
.searchTerm {
  float: left;
  padding: 5px;
  outline: none;
  color: #9DBFAF;
  height: 28px !important;
  border: none !important;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #eaeaea !important;
  padding: 0 4px !important;
}

.searchTerm:focus{
  color: #00B4CC;
}

.searchButton {
  position: absolute;  
  right: 0;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border: transparent;
  background: transparent;
  text-align: center;
  color: #8e8e8e;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 16px;
 margin-top: 4px !important;
}

/*Resize the wrap to see the search bar change!*/
.brand-search-wrap{
  width: 100%;
}

/**** Alpabet list ****/
.page-content ul {
   list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0 12px;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #eaeaea;
    align-items: center;
    flex-basis: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }
.page-content ul li {
   cursor: pointer;
   text-align: center;
   display: flex;
   flex-grow: 1;
   padding: 12px 4px;
   transition: 0.4s;
  }
.AddContent:before {
   content: attr(data-content);
   display: block;
   font-size: 20px;
   margin: auto;
   transition: 0.4s;
  }
 .page-content ul li:hover,
 .page-content ul li:focus { 
         background-color: #444;
   }
   .AddContent:hover:before,
   .AddContent:focus:before   
 {
         color: #fff;
   }   

/*** link-list box ****/
.link-list.box {
    padding: 0 0 2px 2px;
 }
.link-list__header {
    text-align: left;
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 1.25rem;
    position: relative;
    top: 8px;
    left: 52px;
    padding: 0;
    min-height: 0 !important;
    line-height: 1;
}
.link-list__background {
    padding-top: 0;
    height: 56px;
    padding: 8px 0 0 16px;
}
.link-list__image {
     width: 12% !important;
     padding: 0;
     position: relative;
     bottom: 24px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Brands</h1>
<div class="brand-search-wrap">
   <div class="search">
      <input type="text" class="searchTerm" id="searchTerm" placeholder="Enter the brand name here">
      <button type="submit" class="searchButton">
        <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
      </button>
   </div>
</div>
  <div class="page-content"></div>
<article class="category-list">
    <nav class="link-list">
      <a href="/brands/abus" title="ABUS">ABUS</a>
    </nav>
    <nav class="link-list">
      <a href="/brands/abus" title="ACC">ACC</a>
    </nav>
    <nav class="link-list">
      <a href="/brands/abus" title="BUS">BUS</a>
    </nav>
    <nav class="link-list">
      <a href="/brands/abus" title="BKUS">BKUS</a>
    </nav>
    <nav class="link-list">
      <a href="/brands/abus" title="KUS">KUS</a>
    </nav>
    <nav class="link-list">
      <a href="/brands/abus" title="SUK">SUK</a>
    </nav>
    <nav class="link-list">
      <a href="/brands/abus" title="YUG">YUG</a>
    </nav>
  </article>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The core of your problem is how the [':hidden' selector](https://api.jquery.com/hidden-selector/) works in jQuery.

This is the line of code where your concept fails:

```
if(item.find('a').get().length==item.find('a:hidden').get().length) {
```

At his point, the `<a>` elements in question might themselves be visible (filtering correctly removes `display:none` from them), but their parent `nav.link-list` items might currently be hidden, so the  element itself is still matched by the `:hidden` selector:

> Elements can be considered hidden for several reasons: ...
>   * An ancestor element is hidden, so the element is not shown on the page.

So you need to find another way of marking hidden  elements, such as marking them with some css class.

Post back in case you need further assistance here.

**UPDATE**

Here are the relevant parts of your code, updated to reflect my proposed change replacing the `:hidden` selector by some custom class:

First, toggle a class `hidden` in addition to showing/hiding the `<a>` elements (mind the `addClass`/`removeClass` statements):

```
        if (brand.toLowerCase().indexOf(inputValue) > -1) {
            checkEmpty.push('1');
            $(this).fadeIn(800).removeClass('hidden');
        } else {
            $(this).css("display", "none").addClass('hidden');
        }
```

Then, check for this class instead of using the `:hidden` selector (replacing `:hidden` by `.hidden`):

```
if(item.find('a').get().length==item.find('a.hidden').get().length) {
```

It's simple as that.

Comment: Actually, I want to hide the parent nav.link-list if all children <a> are hidden, else show the parent nav so the matched results wrapped by <a> will be shown up. So what is the correct way to make such comparison as the condition then?